# How to know if Offset is inside circle

Tags: flutter

In my code I have `CircleAvatar` with border. I want to know if user tap exactly on border. For this I need to check if tap is inside big circle (`Container`), but not inside small circle (`CircleAvatar`).
Does anybody know how could I check this?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Listener(
    child: Container(
      key: key,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.yellow),
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(widget.imgSrc),
        radius: 60.0,
      ),
    ),
    onPointerDown: (event) {
      if (renderBox == null) {
        renderBox = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
      }
      Rect rect = renderBox.paintBounds;
      // todo ......
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best way, but I've found some solution

```
Rect bigRect = renderBox.paintBounds.shift(renderBox?.localToGlobal(Offset.zero));
Rect smallRect = bigRect.deflate(padding);
Path path = Path()
  ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
  ..addOval(bigRect)
  ..addOval(smallRect);
if (path.contains(event.position)) { // todo...
```

P.S. Muldec's solution can be used too, it works, but I was looking for another type, like `contains`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Pythagore theorem to check if the Offset is in a circle :

```
import 'dart:math';

/// check if a [point] is in a circle of a given [radius]
bool isPointInside(Offset point, double radius) =>
  pow(point.dx, 2) + pow(point.dy, 2) < pow(radius, 2);
```

Do this for the big and small circle and check if the results match what you want.

Edit : removed the sqrt in favour of pow(radius) as suggested by @randal-schwartz

Comment: No point in using sqrt... just square both sides! `pow(point.dx, 2) + pow(point.dy, 2) < pow(radius, 2)`

Comment: Thanks, but I have `Offset` with absolute coordinates. So for this method I have to consider this and change `dx` and `dy`. Without it method always returns false. I tried to find something like method `contains(Offset offset)` of `Rect` class.

Comment: If you know the absolute offset of the center of the circle, you can substract it to the offset of the tap and the method will work.